# QFileSystemModel retrieve filepath of clicked file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qfilesystemmodel

I am trying to create a file explorer where you can look up a file. When found, the user should be able to select the file he want to upload. Therefore I need the path of the selected file.

Here is my current code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Explorer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Explorer, self).__init__()

        self.resize(700, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("File Explorer")
        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.fileSystemModel = QFileSystemModel(self.treeView)
        self.fileSystemModel.setReadOnly(True)

        root = self.fileSystemModel.setRootPath("C:")
        self.treeView.setModel(self.fileSystemModel)

        Layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        Layout.addWidget(self.treeView) 
        self.setLayout(Layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    fileExplorer = Explorer()
    fileExplorer .show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I get the path of the file the user clicked on?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to obtain the path we must use the [`QFileSystemModel::filePath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#fileName) method:

> **QString QFileSystemModel::filePath(const QModelIndex &index) const**
>
> Returns the path of the item stored in the model under the index
> given.

This requires a QModelIndex, this can be obtained through the clicked signal of QTreeView. For this we must connect it to some slot, in this case:

```
    self.treeView.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

def onClicked(self, index):
    # self.sender() == self.treeView
    # self.sender().model() == self.fileSystemModel
    path = self.sender().model().filePath(index)
    print(path)
```

Complete code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Explorer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Explorer, self).__init__()

        self.resize(700, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("File Explorer")
        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.treeView.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.fileSystemModel = QFileSystemModel(self.treeView)
        self.fileSystemModel.setReadOnly(True)

        self.fileSystemModel.setRootPath("C:")
        self.treeView.setModel(self.fileSystemModel)

        Layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        Layout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.setLayout(Layout)

    def onClicked(self, index):
        path = self.sender().model().filePath(index)
        print(path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    fileExplorer = Explorer()
    fileExplorer .show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I didn't know that .connect works also for the QTreeView :/